# How to find exact match for a word in a string

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like this

```
This is just a test-like thing. I want to test this
```

I want to use a regex that will match test, such that it only matches test alone but not something like test-like. What would be the regex for this. I tried "\btest\b" but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please include the complete code that you tried?

Comment: Hyphen is a word boundary. What constites words? Is "it's" a word? Or word-like?

Comment: What about `This is a test.`?

Answer (score 3):

```
(?<=\\s|^)test(?=\\s|$)
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/rA7aS3/14

`\btest\b` wont work cause `-` is a word boundary.

Answer (score 2):

The word boundary `\\b` won't work in this case, as the hyphen `-` is considered to be a "non-word" character too.

Use this instead, with whitespace:

```
String test = "This is just a test-like thing. I want to test this";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\s|^)test(?=\\s|$)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(String.format("Found %s at index %d%n", m.group(), m.start()));
}
```

**Output** (pun not intended)

```
Found test at index 42
```

Comment: @vks I haven't plagiarized your answer. Just worked on mine before seeing yours. It isn't in fact the same. Mine displays actual Java code (now yours too, **after** edit). Mine also displays an index for the match, yours doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try below regex:

```
\stest(\.|\s)
```